# Hostent returning null from char* . Works with hardcoded address

Tags: sockets, char, gethostbyname, hostent

people.

I know hostent is deprecated but have to use it for a project.

For some reason if I do this...

```
hp = getbyhostname ("www.google.com");
```

hp works all right.

But then, if I do this:

```
char *addre;
addre = someFunction();
printf ("The address is %s", addre);
hp = gethostbyname (addre);
```

where someFunction() returns a char*, printf works fine and displays the address correctly, but hp returns null.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: How is the memory that contains the string pointed to by `addre` allocated? Is it with `malloc()`? I suspect that `someFunction()` might be returning the address of a stack variable. Do you have all your compiler warning flags on (because the compiler can sometimes warn about errors like that)?

Comment: The problem was in someFunction() apparently. It was using strtok to do some string tokening and the delimiter I was using was "\n" . Trouble is, I was reading a HTTP GET header to take out the hostname, so I had to token it using the delimiter "\r\n"